# R sequence function in Python

Tags: python, pandas

pandas version: 1.2

I am trying to take a python pandas dataframe column pandas and create the same type of logic as in R that would be

```
ss=sequence(df$los)
```

Which produces for the first two records

```
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5
```

Example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('test', 5), ('t2', 5), ('t3', 2), ('t4', 6)],
                  columns=['first', 'los'])
df

  first  los
0  test    5
1    t2    5
2    t3    2
3    t4    6
```

So the first row is sequenced 1-5 and second row is sequenced 1-5 and third row is sequenced 1-2 etc. In R this becomes one sequenced list. I would like that is python.

What I have been able to do is.

```
ss = df['los']
ss.apply(lambda x: np.array(range(1, x)))
18                          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
90                          [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
105                                   [1,2]
106                      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Which is close but then I need to combine it into a single pd.Series so that it should be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html):

```
df.los.apply(lambda x: np.arange(1, x+1)).explode().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Note - you can skip the `ss` assignment step, and use `np.arange` to streamline a bit.

Comment: Not sure why but this is not giving me the correct sequenca array, it has extra numbers. An my actual dataset my dataframe has been repeated by the same 'los' number has 1363 records. the answer by Quang Hoang produceds 1363 records. This answer produces 1393.
using just `ss2 = dis.los.explode().tolist()` produces 1363

Comment: Interesting.  Do you get the correct sequence when you run on the test data you provided?

Comment: Update: this is the CORRECT answer, Quang's answer did not provide the correct sequence but this does mimic R's sequence function

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `concatenate`:

```
np.concatenate([np.arange(x)+1 for x in df['los']])
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```